# Draggable not working after append

Tags: jquery, draggable

Im having trouble making my buttons draggable after an append() through an ajax call.

Does anyone see an obvious error? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#exAutoTxt").keypress(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("exerciseAutocomplete")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'term': $("#exAutoTxt").val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                var exArray = JSON.parse(data);
                $(".exResults").html("");
                for (var x = 0; x < exArray.length ; x++) {
                    $(".exResults").append("<button class='exNameBtn btn'>" + exArray[x] + "</button> <br/> <br/>");
                }


                $('.exNameBtn').draggable();

            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons fire a request on click by default. you need to disable this with `cancel: false` to enable dragging:

```
$('.exNameBtn').draggable({cancel: false;});
```